# Adding a custom font to a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8

I've read articles such as this [31 days of windows phone day 24 embedding-fonts](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/) and this [windows 8 xaml tips custom fonts](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2012/windows-8-xaml-tips-custom-fonts) that explain very clearly and simply how to do this.

But for some reason I can't figure out, my custom font doesn't show on my app, whether in the designer view or when I run it.

To be sure I haven't left any step out, I'm showing what I did here for any suggestions on what my issue might be:

**1.** First, this is my xaml textblock code

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BottomPanel" Height="120" Width="800" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneSemitransparentColor}"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MainTextBlock" FontFamily="/Fonts/KOMIKAX_.ttf" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" Width="680" Height="120" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="25" Padding="20,10"/>

</StackPanel>
```

**2.** I created a folder in my project, called it "Fonts" and that is where I copied my font file.

**3.** I changed the `Build Action` of the font file to `Content`. I left the `Copy To Output Directory` property as `None` at first, then changed it to `Copy If Newer`. No success.

What have I done wrong or what did I leave out?

Comment: Using the file name as font family looks weird... Did you open the ttf to see the real name of the font? Normally I would use someting like ".\Fonts\MyCustomFont.ttf#Custom font name"

Comment: The real name of the font is "Komika Axis" but aren't you supposed to use the file name, not the font name in the `FontFamily` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MainTextBlock" FontFamily=".\Fonts\KOMIKAX_.ttf#Komika Axis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" Width="680" Height="120" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="25" Padding="20,10"/>
```

In case this doesn't work, remember the format is .\FontPath\FontFileName.ttf#FontName

Comment: the syntax is wrong. it should be. with forward Slash. /

Answer (score 6):

This work for me.

First make a folder in your App with the name Fonts, then Add font to it, then use the following syntax. I used it, it works perfectly.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="/Fonts/Comic.ttf#Comic" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" FontSize="25"/>
```

Make sure that the Build Action must be set to Content, 
Right Click on font in folder and click property, then select Build Action as Content, otherwise it will not work on Emulator and Device.