# Can't use custom font on my app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I downloaded a font, and I created a folder `Fonts` inside the `Assest` in my project and used the following XAML code to set the font.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Height="107"
           Margin="154,75,0,0"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Text="Brain Train"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="310"
           FontSize="60"
           FontFamily="./Assets/Fonts/Foxes In Love.ttf#Foxes In Love"
           FontWeight="Thin" 
           Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

In the **Designer**, when I add the Upper XAML Code, the font changes but when I run the app the font is set to default (not the Custom).

Why?

Comment: Make small changes according to this link

[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449031/adding-a-custom-font-to-a-windows-phone-8-app

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani I already saw that , and done the same , didn't work

Answer (score 0):

MAKE small changes in your path according to this link

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449031/adding-a-custom-font-to-a-windows-phone-8-app)

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="107" Margin="154,75,0,0"
 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Brain Train" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Width="310" FontSize="60"
 FontFamily=".\Fonts\Foxes In Love.ttf#Foxes In Love" FontWeight="Thin" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: have you followed file path format is .\FontPath\FontFileName.ttf#FontName